# Jquery responsive Masonry mobile grid layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-masonry, masonry

### I would like to create a paid subscription website in Jquery mobile because I think the site works better with the server then Wordpress. Of course there will be PHP in it for contact page, etc, but I prefer a responsive Jquery site with a Jquery mobile ui.

My question is I'd like to create a landing page with a few different sized divs similiar to Masonry.js.

---

The layout I want to create is here:
http://themeforest.net/theme_previews/1921894-vivid-jqueryhtml-template?index=1&url_name=vivid-jqueryhtml-template at that link.  Links to some tutorials on the far left, a small slider to the right, then below both of those internal call-to-action links and more fun posts.

How would I manipulate the integrated ui-grid-layout-b seen here http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_grid_responsive in jquery to achieve this other layout?

Could you provide a example to a second page with back button.  I'm having trouble setting up the Ajax as well.  I am using Dreamweaver to stamp out the basic layout. Thanks.

Comment: "Masonry". You'd do well to use spellcheck, proper capitalization and paragraph breaks.

Comment: I think that jQueryMobile has a lot of very specific requirements and is not as configurable as one might expect (coming from plain jQuery). There are other mobile frameworks that would make this very easy. jQuery mobile is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with Jquery Mobile, you can edit the UI grid layout if you so choose to do so, but it could cause X number of bugs and may not play ball with the Jquery Mobile setup, I'd recommend using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) as it's one of the most flexible frameworks out there that support multiple devices and in your case, provides an extremely flexible grid layout system.